# Google+ writeMoment not working in sample code

Tags: android, google-plus

Moments appear broken to me.  Using the google/google_play_services/samples/plus app I can Sign in, and I can Send an interactive post, but none of the Write Moment examples work. From the sample app I can select "List & remove moments" and a list of moments that I assume were created by the sample app, are listed but I don't know where they went.  They weren't posted on my Google+ site unless they go in a specific place I am not checking.  Has anyone been able to use writeMoment() successfully?

After a few minutes, this appears in the Logcat window:

01-27 17:11:31.179    1220-4693/? D/GooglePlusPlatform﹕ Unexpected response code (400) when requesting: writeMoment
01-27 17:11:31.199    1220-4693/? W/GooglePlusPlatform﹕ {"code":400,"errors":[{"message":"Missing metadata field: http://schema.org/url.","domain":"global","reason":"badRequest"}]}

Answer (score 0):

Writing moments from the SDK sample works for me.

1. Make sure that you have updated to the latest version of GMS, it's possible that the sample you are using is an older one.
2. Make sure that all the members of moments are being set. In particular, the Type of the items in the ItemScope.

The following example constructs a moment object for a review activity.

```
ItemScope rating = new ItemScope.Builder()
   .setType("http://schema.org/Rating")
   .setRatingValue("100")
   .setBestRating("100")
   .setWorstRating("0")
   .build();

ItemScope result = new ItemScope.Builder()
    .setType("http://schema.org/Review")
    .setName("A Humble Review of Widget")
    .setUrl("https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/examples/review")
    .setDescription("It is amazingly effective")
    .setReviewRating(rating)
    .build();

ItemScope target = new ItemScope.Builder()
    .setUrl(targetUrl)
    .build();

Moment moment = new Moment.Builder()
    .setType("http://schemas.google.com/ReviewActivity")
    .setTarget(target)
    .setResult(result)
    .build();
```

Additional information on building ItemScope / Moment objects can be found in the [Google+ Android Developer documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/app-activities).

Comment: I have the latest Google Play services revision 14 installed and have  built and run the Plus example included without any changes. If I can't get their own sample working I don't have much hope using any other sample code.  I've tried targeting Android 2.3.3, Android 4.0.3, Google Api's 4.2 and I've run on devices running Android 2.3.4, 4.0.4, 4.1.2.